# Two fields unique

Tags: django

I have two fields in my model, 
number and series, What I want is that these fields are not repeated among the other records, example R1: Series: A and number: 1, which does not allow these two records to be repeated in the future if it already exists

Comment: If a record would be created that duplicates those fields, what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Hello, welcome! I think you'll get better answers if you post a [mcve].

Comment: I wish I could catch the error, stop the insertion and be able to show something in the template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together)

Here is an example of what that model might look like:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    series = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    number = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta(object):
        unique_together = "series", "number"
```